# File serving using ngRoute in Angular with NodeJS server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, url-routing, ngroute

I am trying to run AngularJS, using Angular Router, with a NodeJS server. I do not plan on serving the various views in Node, but instead I want to use the angular router. This first page is served correctly with no errors but when I try to click on another link, the browser displays the following 
[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DroG.png). Below is the relevant code from the server script, the routing script, and where the link in the HTML is.

**HTML Link**

```
<li><a href="./add">Add Workout</a></li>
```

**Server.js**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/home.html'));
});

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module("fitness2Uapp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/", {
          templateUrl : "./app/views/home.html"
      })
      .when("/browse", {
          templateUrl : "./app/views/browse.html"
      })
      .when("/add", {
          templateUrl : "./add.html"
      })
      .when("/workout", {
          templateUrl : "./app/views/workout.html"
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in a "catch all" route that just redirects back to the main page.  This will in turn allow the angular routing mechanism to kick in.  Right now the problem is that it's trying to find an endpoint path of '/add' on the node server, but nothing is found.  This should be the ***very last*** route established on your server.

I personally use AngularJS and had to do this, and everything works great.  Not sure if this will also perform the same way as Angular2+

```
// Catch all if all other routes fail to match.
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(`${__dirname}/path/to/home.html`));
});
```

Comment: This worked in the sense that it doesn't draw an error when the URL is typed in, however, the browser stalls out seeming to be caught in an infinite loop.